# Undefined variable: product in blade view

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined, laravel-blade

```php
<div class="row">
    @foreach($product as $data)
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('image/product_image/'.$data->product_image) }}" alt="photo"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a href="#">{{ $data->product_name }}</a>
                    </h4>
                    <h5>{{ $data->product_price }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $data->product_description }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code of related method.

Comment: add product variable from controller.

Comment: The `$product` variable doesn't exist in your blade. Maybe it is supposed to be `$products` ?

Comment: What is in your controller? Have you sent the `product` to the view?

Comment: Upload your controller's method here ?

Comment: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Answer (score 0):

First collect what you want in the controller. It could be something like this:

```
$product = Product::all();
```

And then you must send the `product` variable to the view. Something like this:

```
return view('path.to.view', compact('product'));
```

By the way. it's better to use plural form `products`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add the code in the blade to retrieve all the products from the product model    


<div class="row">
    @php
    $product = App\Product::all();
    @endphp
        @foreach($product as $data)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('image/product_image/'.$data->product_image) }}" alt="photo"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <a href="#">{{ $data->product_name }}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <h5>{{ $data->product_price }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ $data->product_description }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

Controller's `index` method,

```
public function index()
{
       $product = Product::all();
       return view('path', compact('product'));
}
```